# How to retrieve or pass custom argument TFS Build XAML in Post Build Powershell script

Tags: powershell, xaml, tfs, build, arguments

I have created a new template from default build template for Visual Studio 2013 and created a new custom argument `Brand` to prompt parameter during queue new build.

I tried to read the build argument in the post-build script within Powershell scripts. But the value is always empty.

I used `$env:Brand` passing parameter to post build arguments like `-arg $(Brand)` with and without double quotes.  But is shows empty.

Please help how to retrieve Build arguments in the Post Deploy scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is **resolved** by adding custom argument into Environment variables to the **Run Script** Task XAML definition.

New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"Key", Value}}

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are setting up your property to take your custom parameter. Something like

```
<x:Property Name="BuildEnvironmentName" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
```

Set it up so that it's shown as an option when you queue the build. For example

```
<mtbw:ProcessParameterMetadata Category="Build" ParameterName="BuildEnvironmentName" DisplayName="Target Environment"  Description="The environment where the deployment will take place" Required="true" BrowsableWhen="Always" />
```

If you want to pass this parameter to the post build script, you will need to pass it in your Xaml. An an example

```
<mtba:RunScript DisplayName="Run Post-build Script" FilePath="PostBuildScript" Arguments='[BuildEnvironmentName]' Result="PostBuildScriptResult]" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low"/>
```